# Android - Speech recognition one word?

Tags: android, speech-recognition, voice-recognition, speech

Is there a way to get `SpeechRecognizer` to listen, wait for one word, then stop listening? I only need the first word that the user speaks.

Comment: Why don't you just take the first word from the data received using Java code.

Comment: I want the SpeechRecognizer to stop listening after the first word. The user would be prompted to only say a single word but sometimes the user won't listen or will "mess up".

Comment: I have not used this but this flag will definitely help you android.speech.extras.SPEECH_INPUT_MINIMUM_LENGTH_MILLIS". Documentation defines this as "The minimum length of an utterance. We will not stop recording before this amount of time."

Comment: Have to tried listening for partial results and stopping recognition after 1st partial result has arrived ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use:

`EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT_COMPLETE_SILENCE_LENGTH_MILLIS`

flag rather than:

`SPEECH_INPUT_MINIMUM_LENGTH_MILLIS` flag.

If we set `EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT_COMPLETE_SILENCE_LENGTH_MILLIS` flag than the speech recognition will terminate after the specified time in millis of silence. So in your case the user speaks a word and pauses for 100 milliseconds it will give you the word only. Below is the code I've used and tested also. Edit the time of silence as per your requirement. Just call this function in your activity for testing.

```
    public void provideTextToConvert()
{
    Intent speechintent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    speechintent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT_COMPLETE_SILENCE_LENGTH_MILLIS , 100);
    speechintent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,  RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    speechintent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault());
    speechintent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT,
            getString(R.string.speech_prompt));


    try {
        startActivityForResult(speechintent, REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException a) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                getString(R.string.speech_not_supported),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```